# VB6 populate a list box using adodb recordset

Tags: listbox, vb6, populate

I had a form which originally used Listview control but I need to change it into Listbox control. Now here's the original code which use for listview. I'm trying to change it for populate listbox using adodb recordset but keep getting errors. lv1 is the listbox1; lv2 is the listbox2. Listbox doesn't have listitem.

```
Private Sub PopulateListView()
Dim cnPop As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsPop As ADODB.Recordset
Dim lst As ListItem
Dim lngRecs As Long

On Error GoTo ErrPopulate

Set cnPop = New ADODB.Connection
cnPop.CursorLocation = adUseClient
cnPop.Open gcnORA

Set rsPop = New ADODB.Recordset
rsPop.Open sSQL, cnPop, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

lv1.ListItems.Clear
Do While rsPop.EOF = False
    Set lst = lv1.ListItems.Add(, , rsPop!Customer_Number)
    lst.SubItems(1) = rsPop!Customer_Name
    rsPop.MoveNext
Loop

If rsPop.RecordCount > 0 Then
    SelectButtons True
End If

With lblCount
    .Caption = Format((rsPop.RecordCount), "#,##0") & IIf((rsPop.RecordCount) <= 1, " Customer", " Customers") & " found"
    .Refresh
End With

rsPop.Close
cnPop.Close
Set rsPop = Nothing
Set cnPop = Nothing

Exit Sub

ErrPopulate:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Populate Error"

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you put break point and debugged it. If yes which statement its failing ?

Comment: Yes, I put break point and debug it.

Comment: Do While rsPop.EOF = False
    Set lst = lv1.ListItems.Add(, , rsPop!Customer_Number)
    lst.SubItems(1) = rsPop!Customer_Name
    rsPop.MoveNext

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A listview can have multiple columns, you apparently had at least two columns in your previous listview: Customer Number and Customer Name.

A listbox only has one column.  You'll need to decide how to display/add your two columns of data to the listbox.  Don't be confused by the columns property of the listbox, when set to multiple columns, the control still only has a single column of data - it simply snakes and scrolls horizontally instead of scrolling vertically.

Adding an item to the listbox:

```
lv1.Additem rsPop!Customer_Name
```

Listbox documentation: [VB6 Listbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267225(v=vs.60).aspx)